# Cisco ip helper-address

Tags: cisco, router, cisco-ios, dhcp

I am looking at the DHCP documentation and i cannot seam to find how to configure the router to use a loopback interface as the relay-agent. My objective is to use option 82 so that the dhcp server is able to identify the pool to assign ip addresses from and use a loopback ip address as the source ip address of the DHCP request.

I know that Meraki MX routers work this way, does anyone know if this is possible on Cisco routers?

Thanks

Comment: DHCP Option 82 is optional - it is not enabled by default with the `ip helper-address` command. Unlike what you asked in your initial question, it has nothing to do with finding the correct pool - it's used to make sure that the request come from legitimate hosts and the response comes from a legitimate DHCP server.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

You want the relay agent (`ip helper-address`) on the interface of the network for which it is requesting an address. There are no hosts on the loopback, so it makes no sense to put the relay agent on the loopback.

For example, if `interface GigabitEthernet0/1` is connected to the network (`10.11.12.0/24`) from which the host is requesting DHCP service, then you put the relay agent on that interface:

```
interface GigabitEthernet0/1
 ip address 10.11.12.1 255.255.255.0
 ip helper-address <DHCP server address>
!
```

There is no involvement of a loopback or any other router interface.

Comment: I do not understand your comment. My example is using DHCP relay (Option 82). The router interface will intercept the DHCP broadcast request and create the DHCP relay to the DHCP server using Option 82 to get the response from the DHCP server, then relay it back to the requesting host. There really is not much to it.

Comment: you awsers is not answering to my question, when using option 82 i should be able to source DHCP requests from any ip address on the router. option82 i what will allow the dhcp server to identify the correct pool. Some vendors allow you to do this, like Meraki. Actually Meraki does by default and if im not wrong Huawei and HP also allow you to do the same.

Comment: the ip helper-address does not turn on option 82

Comment: The DHCP server will know the correct pool because the interface uses the network to which it is connected to tell the DHCP server which pool to use. The server will have the correct information. The `ip help-address` absolutely _does_ use Option 82. You seem to be trying to make this more complicated than it really is.

Comment: In ios-xe you can specify a source interface, however in IOS that comand is not present https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/ios-xml/ios/ipaddr_dhcp/configuration/xe-3s/dhcp-xe-3s-book/dhcp-relay-svr-option-82-xe.html

Comment: You put the `ip helper-address` command on the interface. If you have three interfaces with different networks, and your DHCP server has a pool for each of the networks. The interfaces will create DHCP Option 82 requests only for the network attached to the interface, and the DHCP server will know which pool to use based on the Option 82 information supplied by the interface. It is really very simple.

Comment: The document to which you linked is about overriding the DHCP relay Option 82, but simply using the DHCP relay Option 82 is as simple as using the `ip helper-address` command on the interface.

Comment: In my scenario i am using Lisp as the routing protocol, this allows to use same vlan on each edge (this is not SDA). therefore for the dhcp packets to be routed to the correct edge i need to be able to source the DHCP request packets from another address. This is just a proof of concept im working on just to learn.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/116539/discussion-between-user3476261-and-ron-maupin).

Comment: @user3476261 I'm failing to see where this becoming so confusing.  All you do is put the `ip helper-address` command along with the IP address of where to send the request (your DHCP server's IP address) and as long as you have a path to it from your device, the request is forwarded to said DHCP server for it to answer the request.

Comment: To understand what I am talking about have a look to cisco SDA architecture specially to the commands that DNA sends to the switches, only then you will understand.

Comment: @user3476261, your question is about using DHCP Option 82 for the DHCP server to use the correct pool: "_My objective is to use option 82 so that the dhcp server is able to identify the pool to assign ip addresses from and use a loopback ip address as the source ip address of the DHCP request._" That is exactly what the `ip helper-address` command does, so your question has an answer. If you have a different question, then start a new question and ask it, but we can only answer the question you asked.

Comment: @user3476261 Look at the comment I posted under your original question. Does that clarify what option 82 is used for a little more?